# Google App Engine - stats on datastore reads for a complete application

Tags: google-app-engine

In order to decrease the cost of an existing application which over-consumes on Datastore reads, I am trying to get stats on the application as a whole.

What I'd like to get for the overall application is stats about the queries that are returning the biggest number of rows during a complete day of production. The cost of retrieving data being $0.70 / million, there is a big incentive to optimise / cache some queries but first I have to understand which query retrieves too much data.

Appstats apparently does not provide this information as the tool's primary driver is to optimise one RPC call.

Does anyone has a magic solution for this one ? One alternative I thought about was to build by myself a tool to log after each query the number of rows returned but that looks like an overkill and will require to open the code.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Hugues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282567/calculating-datastore-api-usage-per-request/

What you can do to measure and optimize is to look at the cost field provided by the LogService. (It's called cpm_usd in the admin panel).

Using this information you can find the most expensive urls and thus optimize its queries.

Comment: Hi skreft, thanks a lot for your help, very much appreciated. It is correct that using what you propose, I could get the cost per URL. However, each URL contains multiple services and each service contains multiple queries. That is, with this solution, I would have to limit the application to one service by URL. Doing this, my web.xml would explode (I have currently more than 100 services). However, thanks a lot for your feedback, it is really a good start and I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: Just to understand, what do you mean by 100 of services by url? How do you differentiate them?

Comment: Hi skreft, in the web.xml I have basically three services : one for customers not connected (called : externalService), one for customers connected (called internalService) and one for admin (called adminService). In the internalService.java file I have different methods (e.g. requestCreateXX, requestDeleteXX, requestRetrieveYY). The code is just calling "internalService.requestCreateXX". Do you see any issue with this ?